# C# Improving SQLite SELECT performance

Tags: c#, sql, performance, sqlite, datetime

I have a program which has an SQLite database with the table: CREATE TABLE files(path TEXT, last_backup DATETIME)

The total database size is 33Mb with about 250000 records in it.

I am running a block of code which will SELECT any records which have the path field matching a string and return the last_backup DATETIME value. If no records are found a DateTime.MinValue is returned.

When I initially ran my program the database was empty so it will of returned the min date every time. Now there are a lot of records to check the program is running the same process much slower.

My code block for querying the table is:

```
internal DateTime lastBackupDate(String file)
{
    DateTime date = DateTime.MinValue;
    string sql = "SELECT * FROM files WHERE path=@param1";
    SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, _connection);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", file);
    SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        date = (DateTime)reader["last_backup"];
    }
    return date;
}
```

My question is, is there anything that can be done to speed this up?

Comment: Maybe SQLite isn't the right tool for the job, maybe try swithcing to MS SQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of reading the data from every line, you should form your SQL query so that it chooses just the record you want:

```
SELECT max(last_backup) FROM files WHERE path=@param1
```

If that's still slow, you should be able to speed it up by adding an [index](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html) on the `path, last_backup` columns. Indexes let you speed up queries like this in databases. (like the idea of keeping a `HashSet<T>` or `Dictionary<,>` of the thing you're looking up so a fast binary search can be done)

Comment: Changing the query to select just one record (like a few other suggested too) made a difference but the index made a really big difference. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you all you need is a single field, you could return just that one instead of all columns:

```
SELECT last_backup FROM files WHERE path=@param1
```

Also, your query seems like it could potentially return multiple rows, but you only use the backup date from the last one. If that's intentional, you could try returning a single row:

```
SELECT last_backup FROM files WHERE path=@param1 LIMIT 1
```

Or:

```
SELECT DISTINCT last_backup FROM files WHERE path=@param1
```

Just some random thoughts...